# Peticion POST a pasarela de pago AddonPayments - Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status - Bloqueo de cors de la petición

Tags: angular, typescript, formularios, cors, http-post

Estoy desarrollando una web API Rest en Angular, y estoy integrando una pasarela de pago de addonpayments. La integración de la pasarela la hago mediante un formulario post con httpClient. El código es el siguiente:

En el código HTML del componente:
[image: Primera mitad del fomrulario en html]
[image: Segunda mitad del fomrulario en html]

En el código de .ts la variable formDatos es un FormGroup con todos los datos de los campos del formulario, y la variable 'form' es un nuevo FormGroup con los datos introducidos y otros nuevos cuyo valor no elige el usuario, de manera que relleno el 'form' con los datos fijos y los del 'formDatos':

[image: Código del componente en typescript 1/2]
[image: Código del componente en typescript 1/2]

Utilizo un servicio con HttpClient para realizar la petición post al enpoint de la pasarela de pago:

[image: Código del servicio]

Por algun motivo el cors me está bloqueando la petición a la pasarela y me salta este error en el inspector de Chrome:

[image: Error al realizar la petición]
[image: Error en Network]

He mirado mucha información acerca del CORS y sigo sin conseguir que no me bloquee la petición, si alguien supiera la solución me ayudaría mucho, Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Bienvenida a la comunidad, te recomiendo que el código lo pongas en formato de texto en vez de con imágenes, ya que estas puede que no funcionen como desees. Pulsa en [edit] y pega tu código

Comment: Si efectivamente es problema de cors, la solución que se me ocurre es que envíes el formulario a tu servidor y desde ahí a AddonPayments

Comment: Te refieres a utilizar un servicio de angular para hacer la petición?